# Calculate grand total per column

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone here help me with this? The problem with this code is that when you add column(add supplier) it can't get the grand total for each total column. Does anyone here know how to solve this? It will be a big help with my project. Thanks in advance. This is my javascript that calculates the total (not the grand total)

```js
$(function() {
  $('#add_supplier').click(function() {
    $('#supplier_table > thead > tr#first-header').append('<th colspan="2" class="supplier_name">Supplier</th>');

    $('#supplier_table > thead > tr#second-header').append(
      '<th>Price</th>' +
      '<th>Total</th>'
    );

    $('#supplier_table > tbody > tr').append(
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control price text-right" ></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control total text-right" readonly></td>'
    );

    $('#grandtotal > tbody > tr').append(
      '<td><input class="form-control" disabled></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control grandtotal text-right" readonly=""></td>'
    );

    refresh_index();
  });

  $('#add_item').click(function() {
    $('#supplier_table tbody').append($("#supplier_table tbody tr:last").clone());
    refresh_index();
  });

  function refresh_index() {
    $('.price').each(function(i) {
      i++;
      $(this).attr('id', 'price-' + i);
      $(this).attr('data-num', i);
      event_handler();
    });

    $('.total').each(function(i) {
      i++;
      $(this).attr('id', 'total-' + i);
    });

    $('.qty').each(function(i) {
      i++;
      $(this).attr('id', 'qty-' + i);
    });

    $('.grandtotal').each(function(i) {
      i++;
      $(this).attr('id', 'grandtotal-' + i);
    });

    $('.supplier_name').each(function(i) {
      i++;
      $(this).attr('id', 'supplier_name-' + i);
    });
  }
  refresh_index();

  function event_handler() {
    $('.price').unbind('keyup').bind('keyup', function() {
      var id = this.id;
      var num = id.split('-');
      var pos = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1;
      var qty = $('#qty-' + pos).val();
      var price = $(this).val();
      var total = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price);

      if (isNaN(total)) {
        var total = 0;
      }

      $('#total-' + num[1]).val(total);

      var num_of_supplier_name = $('.supplier_name').length;
      sum_of_total(num_of_supplier_name);
    });
  }

  function sum_of_total(num) {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".total").each(function() {
      //add only if the value is number
      if (!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val().length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#grandtotal-" + num).val(sum);
  }
});
```

```css
#supplier_table thead th,
td {
  text-align: center;
}

#grandtotal tbody input:disabled {
  border: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add_supplier">Add Supplier</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add_item">Add Item</button>
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="supplier_table">
    <thead>
      <tr id="first-header">
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th colspan="2" class="supplier_name" id="supplier_name-1">Supplier</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="second-header">
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="tbody-tr">
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Mouse" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control qty" value="10" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control price"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control total for_sum-1" readonly=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tbody-tr">
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Keyboard" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control qty" value="20" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control price"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control total for_sum-1" readonly=""></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="tbody-tr">
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Monitor" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control qty" value="30" readonly=""></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control price"></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control total for_sum-1" readonly=""></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="grandtotal">
      <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="form-control" disabled=""></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" disabled=""></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" disabled value="Grand Total : " style="text-align: right;"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control grandtotal text-right" readonly=""></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </table>
</div>
```

Demo [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samtester/bo10g6r2/3/)

Comment: your fiddle seems to work. the grand total is calculated and the numbers seem to be ok

Comment: Yes but when you add column then the grandtotal is not working

Answer (score 0):

The reason is an easy mistake often made in jQuery.
Your code is interpreted at first page load, all subsequent changes in the DOM are ignored.
There is an easy trick to always interpret all .totals.
Make "body" to find all "totals".

```
  function sum_of_total(num) {
    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $("body").find(".total").each(function() {
      //add only if the value is number
      if (!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val().length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#grandtotal-" + num).val(sum);
  }
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/juf54wby/